# Using the Java API to control printer printing PDF files cannot eliminate serrations

Tags: java

When I used the Java API to control the printer to print the PDF file, I found that it could not eliminate the serrations. Because the text in the PDF file does not have the serrations, so I customized a class to implement the Printable interface and implement the print method, and then added the following code in it

```
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Full code:

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)graphics;
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_DEFAULT);
    ...
    ...
}
```

But the effect is still not ideal

Some people say it can be done by adjusting the brush

```
Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(0.7f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
graphics2D.setStroke(stroke);
```

but it also fails

Comment: The JRE does not deal with PDF directly, you are either using a library to process and print PDF or you are sending whole PDF stream to a printer.

In either case the rendering hint should have no effect. 

Consider using some PDF library like iText or PDFBox to do this kind of work.

Comment: Yes, I used itext to send the entire PDF stream to the printer, but I found that it would eventually use Graphics2D rendering, so I set the rendering parameter for Graphics2D, but it didn't work.